# Bullet-items vertically misaligned if \moderncvstyle{casual} is used

Tags: vertical-alignment, itemize, moderncv

In `moderncv 2015/07/28 v2.0.0`, bullet-items are strangely misaligned vertically, but only if `\moderncvstyle{casual}` is used.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{moderncv}  
\moderncvstyle{casual}  
\firstname{John}  
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}  
\section{Section}  
\cventry{1900-2000}{Degree}{University}{something}{more}  
{  
\begin{itemize}  
\item Point 1  
\item Point 2  
\end{itemize}  
}  
\end{document}
```

This results in
[image: bullet points too low]

If the style is changed to classic, everything seems to be fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{moderncv}  
\moderncvstyle{classic}  

\firstname{John}  
\familyname{Doe}  

\begin{document}  
\section{Section}  
\cventry{1900-2000}{Degree}{University}{something}{more}  
{  
\begin{itemize}  
\item Point 1  
\item Point 2  
\end{itemize}  
}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there some meaningful way to work around that issue?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with casual style the bullet is

```
................\U/fontawesometwo/m/n/6 +
```

and with classic it is

```
................\U/mvs/m/n/10.95 {
```

That is the circles come from fontawesome and marvosym respectively. The different height above the baseline is just the choice of the font designers.

You could raise the fa bullets by eg

```
\let\oldlbi\labelitemi
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\raisebox{.15em}{\oldlbi}}
```

in the document preamble.